# Amazon MQ and .NET Core Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-mq

We are using Amazon MQ which internally use ActiveMQ. We can trigger AWS lambda function whenever ActiveMQ receives a message. I wrote a lambda function which reads the message from an SQS event. We have a type called `SQSevent` which we can capture, but in the case of Amazon MQ I don't know what type of function signature to be used.

For SQS we use this:

```
ProcessSQSMessage( SQSEvent event1, ILambdaContext context)
```

I don't know what to use for Amazon MQ:

```
?ProcessMQMessage( ?? )
```

Please help. I don't have access to AWS from local so checking before deploying code.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no out of the box event for MQ according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-mq.html)
To work with AWS you can follow this [recommendation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html) and as described either:

- use default handler with Stream parameter and convert Stream to a [C# class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html) messages. This is how the handler will look like:

  ```
  public Stream MyHandler(Stream stream, ILambdaContext context)
       {
          //converting Stream into MQEvent and function logic
       }
  ```
- Create a custom implementation of [ILambdaSerializer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html). Then decorate your lambda class with `[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(CustomInputDeserializer))]`

Comment: Thanks so much for the immediate response,  I thought of this.. let me check

Comment: I able to read message successfully,  I need to decode the actual message using UTF-8 format  .. Thanks once again.